# Wordpress: AJAX not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm setting up a plugin. Now I'm trying to get an AJAX-PHP code working but I don't get the succeed data and all end with an error.

tracker.php is the main plugin file.

This is the function on my tracker.php that prints the title and some HTML code:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/user-listing.php';

function trez_tracker_user_listing(){
    ?>
    <h1>Tracker - User List</h1>
    <div class="clicker">Click here</div>
    <div id="printer"></div>
    <?php    
}//trez_tracker_user_listing
```

So in user-listing.php I added the following code:

```
function user_listing_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "ajax_user_request", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/tracker/script/ajax_user_request.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'ajax_user_request', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_user_request' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'user_listing_enqueuer' );

function user_fetcher(){
    $result = 'Message to display';
    return $result;
}//user_listing
add_action("wp_ajax_user_fetcher", "user_fetcher");
```

And finally the javascript code in /script/ajax_user_request.js:

```
/* ajax_user_request.js */
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery(".clicker").click( function() {

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "user_fetcher"},
         success: function(response) {
             if(response.type == "success") {
                 jQuery("#printer").html(response)
             }
             else {
                 alert("AJAX error")
             }
         }//success
      })//jQuery.ajax   
    })//Clicker function
})//document ready
```

When clicking on the `<div>`, I just get the alert message "AJAX error".
How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are not returning the JSON data, you are return string through your `user_fetcher` function.

```
function user_fetcher(){
    $result = 'Message to display';
    return $result;
}//user_listing
```

Change the `user_fetcher` function so that it will return the JSON data to the AJAX call.

```
function user_fetcher(){
    $result = 'Message to display';
    echo json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'message'=>$result));
    die(0);
}//user_listing
```

And in jquery check the response like this:

```
success: function(response) {
     if(response.type == "success") {

         // Add message
         jQuery("#printer").html(response.message)
     }
     else {
         alert("AJAX error")
     }
 }//success
```

For the hook `wp_ajax_user_fetcher`, make sure you are using this after logged in, if you are not logged in in the admin section then you have to use `wp_ajax_nopriv_user_fetcher`. Or you can use both:

```
// Work if user is login
add_action("wp_ajax_user_fetcher", "user_fetcher");

// Work if user is not login
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_user_fetcher", "user_fetcher");
```

Comment: Your revision is good but I get the "AJAX error" alert again.

Comment: Check the request URL and the returned data, through developers toolbar in chrome or with firebug.

Comment: It works. I didn't edit the user_fetcher like you suggested. Thank you so much